# WebGL: Zooming to and stopping at object in a scene in WebGL

Tags: webgl

We've created a WebGl application which displays a scene containing multiple objects.  The entire scene can be rotated in multiple directions.  The application requires the user to be able to zoom up to but NOT thru the object.  I know this functionality can be implemented using webgl frameworks such as Three.js and SceneJs.  Unfortunately, our application is not leveraging a framework.  Is there a way to implement the zoom functionality described here using webgl only? Note: I don't believe object picking will work for us since the user is not required to select any object in the scene.   Thanks for your help.

Comment: Assuming your object is centered at (0, 0, 0), just make sure that your camera is always pointing at the origin and at least X units away?

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head.

First off you need to know the size of each object in world space. For example if one object is 10 units big and another is 100 units big you probably want to be a different distance from the 100 unit object as the 10 unit object. By world space I also mean if you're scaling the 10 unit object by 9 then in world space it would be 90 units big and again you'd want to get a different distance away then if it was 10 units

You generally compute the size of an object in local space by computing the extents of its vertices. Just go through all the vertices and keep track of the min and max values in x, y, and z.  Whether you want to take the biggest value from the object's origin or compute an actual center point is up to you.

So, given the size we can compute how far away you need to be to see the entire object. For the standard perspective matrix you can just work backward. If you know your object is 10 units big then you need to fit 10 units in your frustum. You'd probably actually pick something like 14 units (say size * 1.4) so there's some space around the object.

[image]

We know `halfFovy`, `halfSizeToFitOnScreen`, we need to compute `distance`

```
sohcahtoa
tangent = opposite / adjacent
opposite = halfsizeToFitOnScreen
adjacent = distance
tangent  = Math.tan(halfFovY)
```

Therefore

```
tangent = sizeToFitOnScreen / distance
tangent * distance = sizeToFitOnScreen
distance = sizeToFitOnScreen / tangent
distance = sizeToFitOnScreen / Math.tan(halfFovY)
```

So now we know the camera needs to be `distance` away from the object. There's an entire sphere that's `distance` away from the object. Where you pick on that sphere is up to you. Assuming you go from where the camera currently is you can compute the direction from the object to the camera

```
direction = normalize(cameraPos - objectPos)
```

Now you can compute a point `distance` away in that direction.

```
desiredCameraPosition = direction * distance
```

Now either put the camera there using some lookAt function

```
matrix = lookAt(desiredCameraPosition, objectPosition, up)
```

Or lerp between where the camera currently is to it's new desired position

```js
var m4 = twgl.m4;
    var v3 = twgl.v3;
    twgl.setAttributePrefix("a_");
    var gl = twgl.getWebGLContext(document.getElementById("c"));
    var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);

    var shapes = [
      twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 2),
      twgl.primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(gl, 1, 24, 12),
      twgl.primitives.createTruncatedConeBufferInfo(gl, 1, 0, 2, 24, 1),
    ];

    function rand(min, max) {
      return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
    }

    function easeInOut(t, start, end) {
      var c = end - start;
      if ((t /= 0.5) < 1) {
        return c / 2 * t * t + start;
      } else {
        return -c / 2 * ((--t) * (t - 2) - 1) + start;
      }
    }

    // Shared values
    var lightWorldPosition = [1, 8, -10];
    var lightColor = [1, 1, 1, 1];
    var camera = m4.identity();
    var view = m4.identity();
    var viewProjection = m4.identity();
    var targetNdx = 0;
    var targetTimer = 0;
    var zoomTimer = 0;
    var eye = v3.copy([1, 4, -60]);
    var target = v3.copy([0, 0, 0]);
    var up = [0, 1, 0];
    var zoomScale = 1.4;
    var zoomDuration = 2;
    var targetChangeInterval = 3;
    var oldEye;
    var oldTarget;
    var newEye;
    var newTarget;

    var tex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 2, 2, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([
      255,255,255,255,
      192,192,192,255,
      192,192,192,255,
      255,255,255,255]));
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    var objects = [];
    var drawObjects = [];
    var numObjects = 100;
    var baseHue = rand(0, 360);
    for (var ii = 0; ii < numObjects; ++ii) {
      var uniforms = {
        u_lightWorldPos: lightWorldPosition,
        u_lightColor: lightColor,
        u_diffuseMult: chroma.hsv((baseHue + rand(0, 60)) % 360, 0.4, 0.8).gl(),
        u_specular: [1, 1, 1, 1],
        u_shininess: 50,
        u_specularFactor: 1,
        u_diffuse: tex,
        u_viewInverse: camera,
        u_world: m4.identity(),
        u_worldInverseTranspose: m4.identity(),
        u_worldViewProjection: m4.identity(),
      };
      drawObjects.push({
        programInfo: programInfo,
        bufferInfo: shapes[ii % shapes.length],
        uniforms: uniforms,
      });
      objects.push({
        translation: [rand(-50, 50), rand(-50, 50), rand(-50, 50)],
        scale: rand(1, 5),
        size: 2,
        xSpeed: rand(0.2, 0.7),
        zSpeed: rand(0.2, 0.7),
        uniforms: uniforms,
      });
    }

    var then = Date.now() * 0.001;

    function render() {
      twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
      gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

      gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
      gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      var time = Date.now() * 0.001;
      var elapsed = time - then;
      then = time;

      var radius = 6;
      var fovy = 30 * Math.PI / 180;
      var projection = m4.perspective(fovy, gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight, 0.5, 200);

      targetTimer -= elapsed;
      if (targetTimer <= 0) {
        targetTimer = targetChangeInterval;
        zoomTimer = 0;
        targetNdx = (targetNdx + 1) % objects.length;
        oldEye = v3.copy(eye);
        oldTarget = v3.copy(target);
        var targetObj = objects[targetNdx];
        newTarget = targetObj.translation;
        var halfSize = targetObj.size * targetObj.scale * zoomScale * 0.5;
        var distance = halfSize / Math.tan(fovy * 0.5);
        var direction = v3.normalize(v3.subtract(eye, newTarget));
        newEye = v3.add(newTarget, v3.mulScalar(direction, distance));
      }

      zoomTimer += elapsed;
      var lerp = easeInOut(Math.min(1, zoomTimer / zoomDuration), 0, 1);
      eye = v3.lerp(oldEye, newEye, lerp);
      target = v3.lerp(oldTarget, newTarget, lerp);

      m4.lookAt(eye, target, up, camera);
      m4.inverse(camera, view);
      m4.multiply(projection, view, viewProjection);

      objects.forEach(function(obj, ndx) {
        var uni = obj.uniforms;
        var world = uni.u_world;
        m4.identity(world);
        m4.translate(world, obj.translation, world);
        m4.rotateX(world, time * obj.xSpeed, world);
        m4.rotateZ(world, time * obj.zSpeed, world);
        m4.scale(world, [obj.scale, obj.scale, obj.scale], world);
        m4.transpose(m4.inverse(world, uni.u_worldInverseTranspose), uni.u_worldInverseTranspose);
        m4.multiply(viewProjection, uni.u_world, uni.u_worldViewProjection);
      });

      twgl.drawObjectList(gl, drawObjects);

      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
    render();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="//twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chroma-js/0.6.3/chroma.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
uniform vec3 u_lightWorldPos;
uniform mat4 u_world;
uniform mat4 u_viewInverse;
uniform mat4 u_worldInverseTranspose;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

varying vec4 v_position;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToLight;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToView;

void main() {
  v_texCoord = a_texcoord;
  v_position = (u_worldViewProjection * a_position);
  v_normal = (u_worldInverseTranspose * vec4(a_normal, 0)).xyz;
  v_surfaceToLight = u_lightWorldPos - (u_world * a_position).xyz;
  v_surfaceToView = (u_viewInverse[3] - (u_world * a_position)).xyz;
  gl_Position = v_position;
}
  </script>
  <script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_position;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToLight;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToView;

uniform vec4 u_lightColor;
uniform vec4 u_diffuseMult;
uniform sampler2D u_diffuse;
uniform vec4 u_specular;
uniform float u_shininess;
uniform float u_specularFactor;

vec4 lit(float l ,float h, float m) {
  return vec4(1.0,
              abs(l),//max(l, 0.0),
              (l > 0.0) ? pow(max(0.0, h), m) : 0.0,
              1.0);
}

void main() {
  vec4 diffuseColor = texture2D(u_diffuse, v_texCoord) * u_diffuseMult;
  vec3 a_normal = normalize(v_normal);
  vec3 surfaceToLight = normalize(v_surfaceToLight);
  vec3 surfaceToView = normalize(v_surfaceToView);
  vec3 halfVector = normalize(surfaceToLight + surfaceToView);
  vec4 litR = lit(dot(a_normal, surfaceToLight),
                    dot(a_normal, halfVector), u_shininess);
  vec4 outColor = vec4((
  u_lightColor * (diffuseColor * litR.y +
                u_specular * litR.z * u_specularFactor)).rgb,
      diffuseColor.a);
  gl_FragColor = outColor;
}
  </script>
```