# How to use Matrix4.setLookAt to move camera through scene

Tags: javascript, webgl

Trying to make a first person camera controller in webGL.  I'm attempting to do this using the Matrix4.setLookAt() function, but am uncertain how to calculate (and frankly a bit uncertain which parameters I need to be modifying and when) how to move around.  How I currently have implemented to look left and right seems to work alright initially, but once the value nears 1.0 or -1.0 for the g_eyeX values, it begins moving the camera away (in the negative x direction away) from the cube in the scene.  I can't find much documentation on how to utilize this function to move the "camera" around the scene, as most of it references three.js (which I'm trying to learn how this works and don't want to use a library for it).  Could anyone give some help or point me in the right direction?  It would be greatly appreciated

My code is listed below, and here's what the setLookAt function takes as arguments
Matrix4.setLookAt(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, atX, atY, atZ, upX, upY, upZ)

'eyeX, Y, Z' - Specify the position of the eye point
'atX, atY, atZ' - Specify the position of the look-at point
'upX, upY, upZ' - Specify the up direction in the scene

JS:

```
 // sceneWalker.js
    // modified from RotatingTriangle.js (c) 2012 matsuda
    // uses a non-indexed cube - 2 triangles per side - 36 vertices
    // Vertex shader program
    var VSHADER_SOURCE =
      'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
      'uniform mat4 u_ViewMatrix;\n' +
      'uniform mat4 u_ModelMatrix;\n' +
      'uniform mat4 u_ProjMatrix;\n' +
      'void main() {\n' +
      '  gl_Position = u_ProjMatrix * u_ViewMatrix * u_ModelMatrix * a_Position;\n' +
      '}\n';

    // Fragment shader program
    var FSHADER_SOURCE =
      'void main() {\n' +
      '  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n' +
      '}\n';

    // Rotation angle (degrees/second)
    var ANGLE_STEP = 0.0;
    var MOVE_AMOUNT = 0.0;
    var g_eyeX = 0.0, g_eyeY = 0.0, g_eyeZ = 0.25; // Eye position
    var g_curX = 0.0, g_curZ = -3.0;

    function main() {
      // Retrieve <canvas> element
      var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');

      // Get the rendering context for WebGL
      var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
      if (!gl) {
        console.log('Failed to get the rendering context for WebGL');
        return;
      }

      // Initialize shaders
      if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) {
        console.log('Failed to intialize shaders.');
        return;
      }

      // Write the positions of vertices to a vertex shader
      var n = initVertexBuffers(gl);
      if (n < 0) {
        console.log('Failed to set the positions of the vertices');
        return;
      }

      // Specify the color for clearing <canvas>
      gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

      // Get storage location of u_ViewMatrix
      var u_ViewMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_ViewMatrix');
      if (!u_ViewMatrix) { 
        console.log('Failed to get the storage location of u_ViewMatrix');
        return;
      }

      var u_ModelMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_ModelMatrix');
      if (!u_ModelMatrix) { 
        console.log('Failed to get the storage location of u_ModelMatrix');
        return;
      }

      var u_ProjMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_ProjMatrix');
        if (!u_ModelMatrix) { 
            console.log('Failed to get the storage location of u_ProjMatrix');
            return;
        }   
      // Current rotation angle
      var currentAngle = 0.0;
      // Model matrix
      var modelMatrix = new Matrix4();
      var viewMatrix = new Matrix4();
      var projMatrix = new Matrix4();
      modelMatrix.setTranslate(0, 0, 100);
      viewMatrix.setLookAt(g_eyeX, g_eyeY, g_eyeZ, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
      projMatrix.setPerspective(45, (canvas.width)/(canvas.height), 0.1, 10000000);
      gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_ModelMatrix, false, modelMatrix.elements);
      gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_ViewMatrix, false, viewMatrix.elements);
      gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_ProjMatrix, false, projMatrix.elements);

      document.onkeydown = function(ev){ keydown(ev, gl, n, u_ViewMatrix, viewMatrix); };
      // Start drawing
      var tick = function() {
        //currentAngle = animate(currentAngle);  // Update the rotation angle
        draw(gl, n, currentAngle, modelMatrix, viewMatrix, u_ModelMatrix, u_ViewMatrix);   // Draw the triangle
        requestAnimationFrame(tick, canvas); // Request that the browser calls tick
      };
      tick();
    }

    function keydown(ev, gl, n, u_ViewMatrix, viewMatrix) {
    console.log(ev.keyCode);
        if(ev.keyCode == 39) { // The right arrow key was pressed
          g_eyeX -= 0.01;
          console.log(g_eyeX);
        } else 
        if (ev.keyCode == 37) { // The left arrow key was pressed
          g_eyeX += 0.01;
          console.log(g_eyeX);
        }
        if(ev.keyCode == 38){
            g_eyeY += 0.01;
        }
        if(ev.keyCode == 40){
            g_eyeY -= 0.01;
        }
        if(ev.keyCode == 68){
            g_curX -= 0.01;
        }
        if(ev.keyCode == 65){
            g_curX += 0.01;
        }
        if(ev.keyCode == 87){
            g_curZ += 0.01;
        }
        if(ev.keyCode == 83){
            g_curZ -= 0.01;
        }
        else { return; }   
    }


    function initVertexBuffers(gl) {
      var vertices = new Float32Array ([
        -0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
        -0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
        0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
        -0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
        0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
        0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
        0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
        0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
        0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
        0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
        0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
        0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
        0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
        -0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
        0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
        0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
        0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
        -0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
        -0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
        0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
        -0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
        0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
        -0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
        0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
        0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
        0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
        -0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
        -0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
        -0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
        -0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
        -0.5, 0.5, 0.5
      ]);
      var n = 36;   // The number of vertices

      // Create a buffer object
      var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
      if (!vertexBuffer) {
        console.log('Failed to create the buffer object');
        return -1;
      }

      // Bind the buffer object to target
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
      // Write date into the buffer object
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

      // Assign the buffer object to a_Position variable
      var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
      if(a_Position < 0) {
        console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
        return -1;
      }
      gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

      // Enable the assignment to a_Position variable
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);

      return n;
    }

    function draw(gl, n, currentAngle, modelMatrix, viewMatrix, u_ModelMatrix, u_ViewMatrix) {
      // Set the rotation matrix
      modelMatrix.setRotate(currentAngle, 1, 1, 1); 
      modelMatrix.setTranslate(g_curX, 0, g_curZ);

      viewMatrix.setLookAt(g_eyeX, g_eyeY, g_eyeZ, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
      // Pass the rotation matrix to the vertex shader
      gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_ViewMatrix, false, viewMatrix.elements);
      gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_ModelMatrix, false, modelMatrix.elements);

      // Clear <canvas>
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      // Draw the rectangle
      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, n);
    }

    // Last time that this function was called
    var g_last = Date.now();
    function animate(angle) {
      // Calculate the elapsed time
      var now = Date.now();
      var elapsed = now - g_last;
      g_last = now;
      // Update the current rotation angle (adjusted by the elapsed time)
      var newAngle = angle + (ANGLE_STEP * elapsed) / 1000.0;
      return newAngle %= 360;
    }
```

HMTL:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Cube</title>
  </head>

  <body onload="main()">
    <canvas id="webgl" width="400" height="400">
    Please use a browser that supports "canvas"
    </canvas>

    <script src="../lib/webgl-utils.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/webgl-debug.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/cuon-utils.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/cuon-matrix.js"></script>
    <script src="sceneWalker.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [this answer might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29362951/128511). It uses lookAt

Comment: Just a detail (in addition to the ones mentioned in answers):
>      modelMatrix.setRotate(currentAngle, 1, 1, 1); 
>      modelMatrix.setTranslate(g_curX, 0, g_curZ);
The second statement above overwrites the first one.

Answer (score 1):

setLookAt is usually implemented to take 3 vectors (or 9 individual values) as its arguments. The first argument is where the position of eye/camera/you is. The second argument is position along the direction you want to be looking at. The third argument is up axis. This is used to set the orientation of camera. This is needed because there are infinitely many orientations that all shares the same direction. Think of a plane, the direction of plane tells you which way its going but the orientation of plane indicates whether its flying normally or upside down.

The setLookAt usually returns a view matrix (or its inverse) which you then pass to the GPU.

So rather than the three 0s you have as the look position, you probably want to use the position of your model instead? Furthermore, note that your movement implementation currently moves you in absolute coordinates, not based on the current orientation of the camera. +/- 1.0 to eye_x may not actually make you move left in camera space.

Here, for reference, a simple pseudo FPSCamera implementation that should get you started. The main thing to note is that the camera should track its orientation via a forward, up and side vectors. These are in world coordinates and they are normalized to a length of one.

```
/** @constructor */
function FPSCamera(){
    this.pos = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0];

    this.dir = [0.0, 0.0, -1.0]; // or forward
    this.up = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0];
    this.side = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]; // or right
}

FPSCamera.prototype.forward = function(dist){
    this.pos[0] += this.dir[0] * dist;
    this.pos[1] += this.dir[1] * dist;
    this.pos[2] += this.dir[2] * dist;
};
// do the same for other 2 directions, strife and fly

// looks to left/right
FPSCamera.prototype.yaw = function(radians){
    var orientationChange = ORIENTATION.fromAxisAngle(this.up, radians);
    this.dir = VEC3.rotatedByOrientation(this.dir, orientationChange);
    this.side = VEC3.cross(this.dir, this.up);
    this.side = VEC3.normalize(this.side);
};

// same for pitch... except the rotation axis is this.side and you need to ensure the pitch is within +/- 90 degrees

FPSCamera.prototype.getViewMatrix = function(){
    // matrix can be extracted from the 3 direction vectors, but lets use lookAt here;
    return MAT4.lookAt(this.pos, VEC3.plus(this.pos, this.dir), this.up);
};
```

Comment: I'm curious about the solution to this as well since I'm pretty new to vanilla WebGL. Could you provide a jsfiddle with a simple example?

Comment: Its kinda annoying to put 3D stuff to jsfiddle because there is a lot of dependencies as I rather work with my abstractions rather than webgl API directly. I think what I'll do is put up a simple FPS camera implementation and that should get you started.